# Both margins effect each other why?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using a child theme, on one page I want margin left 30 on the other not. But it will effect all pages how do I make it unique?

CSS:

```
.description.style-16 ol, ul {
margin-left: 30px;
}
.eo-events-shortcode ol, ul {
margin-left: 0;               (this one will have no effect)
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="one_third">
 <div id="homeboxheader">
 <h3 class="highlight">Agenda</h3>
 <ul class="eo-events eo-events-shortcode">
 <li class="eo-event-cat-agenda eo-event-future">
 <li class="eo-event-cat-agenda eo-event-future">
 </ul>
 <div id="homebox_tabs">
 </div>


 <div class="one_third">
 <div class="description clearfix style-16">
 <h3 class="highlight">Werken bij SVHW</h3>
 <ul>
 <li>
 <li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

adding the inline to this

```
[one_third]
<div id="homeboxheader">
<h3 class="highlight">Agenda</h3>
[eo_events event_start_before='+1 week' event_category=party,birthday's no_events="no events." showpastevents=false numberposts='3'] <a href="%event_url%">%event_title%</a> %start{D d/m}{, H:i}% till %end{H:i}{}% [/eo_events]
<div id="homebox_tabs">
<div class="homeboxtab">[button link="http://intranet/wordpress/?page_id=2418" size="small" color="blue"]Go to agenda[/button]</div>
</div>
</div>
[/one_third]
```

Comment: Are you working with WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To differentiate the two either adding an ID or class will allow you to specifically target each element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create something that will uniquely identify the page you want it to apply to.

You can either have the CSS apply only if the `<body>` has a certain class; or you could use a second stylesheet, or inline styles for that page.

Comment: Ah i see what you mean, i think the easyest would be inline style. But adding this to a shortcode i dont understand.

Comment: Please see original post i added it